# How to get GPU information in C++ before the drivers are installed

Tags: c++, windows, drivers

We have a piece of software which can run on several different graphics cards, both ATI and NVIDIA. I need to be able to determine either the device id or the model name of the graphics card before its drivers are installed, so that I can create a hard drive image which can be booted up with any of the graphics cards we support, have it detect the graphics card on first boot, install the drivers then restart. Target platform is WinXP.

I tried using WMI but that can only retrieve information about the display adapter, which doesn't include the device id, and before the drivers are installed the display adapter will just has generic data like "Video Controller (VGA)" for the name and so on.

EnumDisplayDevices cannot detect the device until after its drivers are installed.

This must be possible, as when the new hardware wizard opens it knows the name of the graphics card, but I just can't find a way of doing it.

Any ideas?

EDIT - Here's the query

```
ExecQuery(bstr_t("WQL"),bstr_t("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE DeviceID LIKE 'PCI\\VEN'"), WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, NULL, &pEnumerator);
```

Comment: What are you querying for in WMI - do you get more from the general PNP devices list? e.g. in PowerShell `Get-WmiObject Win32_PNPEntity |Where{$_.DeviceID.StartsWith("PCI\VEN_10DE") -or $_.DeviceID.StartsWith("PCI\VEN_1002")}`

Comment: I tried:

ExecQuery(bstr_t("WQL"),bstr_t("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE DeviceID LIKE 'PCI\\VEN'"),  WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, NULL, &pEnumerator);

but this returned no results (i.e. the call to Next() after the query returns 0) so I assumed this only worked once the drivers are installed.

Comment: But that should return lots of results for other PCI devices. There's some notes [on this list of WMI examples on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394587.aspx) that say you should be able to detect PCI devices missing drivers (if not USB devices)

Comment: I can only assume that the query string is incorrect, I'll put it in the main post to make it more readable, but as far as I could tell it looked correct.

Comment: OK, but my point was that if you go into Device Manager on a clean XP install you'll already have lots of PCI devices set up, e.g. all the USB hosts which have drivers installed from the bundle on the CD. So if your query is returning nothing I'd guess it's wrong. Sorry I haven't done WQL in years so I can't tell you what.

Comment: Ok thanks, from just querying for Win32_PnPEntity and printing out all of the results I can see my graphics card's device id in there, so at least now I know that WMI can detect uninstalled devices! That's what I really wanted to know, so it doesn't really matter that I got the full query wrong. Cheers!

Comment: Isn't it possible to just install all drivers by default and have Windows pick the right one?

Comment: Since you've already solved this, I won't bother posting a solution; however just an FYI that this can be done without WMI via EnumDeviceDrivers and SetupAPI.

Comment: @Mahmoud thanks - IMO that's still worth adding as an answer too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future reference for other users I'll add my own answer.

Contrary to what I said in my post, WMI can in fact detect uninstalled devices, by querying for Win32_PNPEntity you can get their device ids.